# load external file into page id in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-mobile

i have an external file profile.php, i want to load it into a sub page id `profile` after clicking a link.. i have tried the code below but i did not see any been displayed after the click event, the clicked event is triggered because i have tested it `alert` , there is no error in console i think i'm missing something please help out. thanks

```
  $(document).on("click", "#profilel",function(){
$( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "load", "profile.php" )
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$(document).on("click", "#profile",function(){
$( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "load", "profile.php" )
 });
```

or

```
$("#profilel").click(function(){
  $.get("profile.php")
     .done(function(data){
      $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).html(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: Im just changed the id "#profilel to #profile" in my first answer in case your id is would be wrong.